# How to serialize static or const member variables using JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I haven't been able to find the answer to this anywhere, but when I try to serialize a struct or class with static or const member variables, they don't serialize by default.  If I try to force serialization by setting `MemberSerialization.OptIn`, I get an error.

ex.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{    
    [JsonProperty]
    public int x = 1;

    [JsonProperty]
    public static int y = 2;
}
```

If I try to serialize this class with:

```
Test t = new Test();
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( t );
```

I get the error `Error getting value from 'y' on 'Test'`.  The same happens if y is const.

My theory is that static and const values are stored somewhere special in memory, and for some reason the Json serializer dies trying to access them.  That's entirely a hunch though, and I see nothing in the [C# Reference for Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/98f28cdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's of any help.  I'm relatively new to C# - and this is really a curiosity question more than anything at this point.

Comment: It is not related to *some memory*.  If you consider serialization as taking the snapshot of an instance of a class, static variables are not part of *instances*.

Comment: I can't imagine why anyone would need to serialize static and even less so const as a part of JSON object. With const it is especially interesting... how do you deserialize into a constant?

Comment: There are other use case to serializing AS JSON than deserializing back to the same type (for example, using a serialized C# object in javascript). So you could need to serialize it if it's part of the data you're interested in and the class itself isn't available wherever you're using the json

Comment: @Stilgar then you're not very imaginative my friend. The JSON gets sent to our server. The server deals with the data in both python and javascript. The static value is a version identifier that tells the server what client version this is, so it may treat various clients differently.  That should be static data.  I used `readonly` and initialized the variable within the class definition, making it instance data, but really, IMO a version specifier should be static.  **Also** the question says *serialize* not *deserialize*.

Comment: @L.B yep, makes perfect sense when I consider it that way.  I guess it's kind of a dumb question now that I look at it since I also can't access the value y using `t.y`...  Oh well.  Sometimes dumb questions need to be asked...

Comment: If it is the same for all objects it is better to send it in some sort of header object rather than make it part of your actual data.

Comment: The data is stored in a database, and needs the version to be stored with it, so when it's retrieved from the DB we still know what version it is.  Hence, it's part of the data.  The actual use case goes much more in depth, and often I'd agree with you there, but in this case, it needs to be part of the object.

Comment: @wallacer if you want to use it as a version, then it can not be static since two instances of your class may have different versions.

Comment: @L.B Who says I want two instances of the class to have different versions?  If the class is always instantiated on the client, then sent to the server, and I want the version to be tied to the client, then I would want all instances of the class to have the same version.  ;)  The question says *serialize* not *deserialize*. Regardless, I intentionally left my use case out of the question and posed this as a general curiosity question.  Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @wallacer See the server side. Your clients pass that class to your server who have different versions :)

Comment: @L.B You're assuming my server side is written in C# ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It could certainly serialize the static variable if it wanted to. Serialization is done by inspecting objects and types with the Reflection APIs, and those APIs allow you to do "anything" -- there is no technical reason these values cannot be serialized.

There is, however, a logical reason not to support this by default: it doesn't make much sense. You are serializing an *instance*, and `static` or `const` members are not logically part of an instance but of the class as a whole.

That said, you can still serialize `static` member if it's a property:

```
[JsonProperty]
public static int y { get; set; } // this will be serialized
```

And of course you can completely override the serializer's behavior by creating a custom `JsonConverter`.

Comment: Thanks. At first I was surprised, not so much that the default was to leave static and const members out, as that my attempt to force them in gave a Runtime error.  Good to know that static properties can be serialized.

Answer (score 14):

As of Json.NET 6.0.4, static and const member variables, as well as static properties, will be serialized when marked with [`[JsonProperty]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm).  From the [release notes](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/6.0.4):

> - Fix - Fixed serializing static fields

Thus serializing the following class:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{    
    [JsonProperty]
    int x = 1;

    [JsonProperty]
    static int y = 2;

    [JsonProperty]
    const int z = 333;
}
```

Produces `{"x":1,"y":2,"z":333}`.  Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0UPaz9).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static string SerializeStaticClass(System.Type a_Type)
{
        var TypeBlob = a_Type.GetFields().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(null));
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TypeBlob);
}
```

I did that to serialize all of our static class constants out to a JS file, then bundled that file into an angular app.  You attach the generated js objects to $rootScope and all the angular code has access to the constants.

[hat tip here](http://www.codedisqus.com/0NJekXqeWX/share-constants-between-c-and-javascript-in-mvc-razor.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a static member (or const) to be serialized on each instance, you could use a private instance-level accessor as a workaround:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int x = 1;

    // static member we want serialized with each instance
    public static int y = 2;

    // private accessor to allow Json.net to serialize the static member
    [JsonProperty("y")]
    private int y1 { get { return y; } }
}
```

Should you need to deserialize to this class as well, this approach will prevent Json.Net from overwriting the static member while still allowing your own code to modify it if needed.