# How to serialize static properties in JSON.NET without adding [JsonProperty] attribute

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it possible to serialize static properties with JSON.NET without adding [JsonProperty] attribute to each property.
Example class:

```
public class Settings
    {
        public static int IntSetting { get; set; }
        public static string StrSetting { get; set; }

        static Settings()
        {
            IntSetting = 5;
            StrSetting = "Test str";
        }
    }
```

Expected result:

```
{
  "IntSetting": 5,
  "StrSetting": "Test str"
}
```

Default behavior skips static properties:

```
var x = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Settings(), Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Please view this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597/why-cant-json-net-serialize-static-or-const-member-variables

Comment: It should be possible using a custom converter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with a custom contract resolver. Specifically you need to subclass `DefaultContractResolver` and override the `GetSerializableMembers` function:

```
public class StaticPropertyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var baseMembers = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);

        PropertyInfo[] staticMembers = 
            objectType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        baseMembers.AddRange(staticMembers);

        return baseMembers;
    }
}
```

Here all we're doing is calling the base implementation of `GetSerializableMembers`, then adding `public static` properties to our list of members to serialize.

To use it you can create a new `JsonSerializerSettings` object and set the `ContractResolver` to an instance of the `StaticPropertyContractResolver`:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();

serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new StaticPropertyContractResolver();
```

Now, pass those settings to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and everything should work:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Settings(), serializerSettings);
```

Output:

```
{
  "IntSetting": 5,
  "StrSetting": "Test str"
}
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/pswTJW

Answer (score 1):

A more complicated way to solve this:

**Solution 1:**

```
public class Settings
{
    int intsetting { get; set; } /*= 0;*/ // commented only allowed in C# 6+
    string strsetting { get; set; } /*= "";*/

    public int IntSetting { get { return intsetting; } set { intsetting = value; } }
    public string StrSetting { get { return strsetting; } set { strsetting = value; } }

    static Settings()
    {
        IntSetting = 5;
        StrSetting = "Test str";
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** (less complicated)

```
public class Settings
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public static int IntSetting { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public static string StrSetting { get; set; }

    static Settings()
    {
        IntSetting = 5;
        StrSetting = "Test str";
    }
}
```

Adding the `[JsonProperty]` to all variables would be the easyest way of solving this, but when you don't want to use it **Solution 1** would fit best for you.

Comment: I was thinking there is a way to implement/override default JsonConverter behavior like recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597/why-cant-json-net-serialize-static-or-const-member-variables. But I guess it's not a trivial solution.