# JSON Static Properties Serialization Not Working

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm aware of why serialization of static variables would by default not work, but the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597/why-cant-json-net-serialize-static-or-const-member-variables) seem to indicate that it is possible with the correct attributes.

My class looks like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class c
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public static double x{ get; set; } = 70;
    [JsonProperty]
    public static double y{ get; set; } = 36;
    [JsonProperty]
    public static double z{ get; set; } = 12;
}
```

And it enters JSON.net through

```
StatePersister.SaveState(new c(), fileName);


public static void SaveState(Object o, string savePath, FileFormat? format = null)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(o.GetType(), settings);
    using (var stream = File.Create(savePath))
    {
        using (var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "\t"))
        {

            serializer.WriteObject(writer, o);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried it with and without the [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)] attribute and either way I get a file that only contains "{}"

Stepping through the code I know the object is being instantiated, and it is being passed in the right object with the right information.

Comment: Why do you have static properties anyway? Why not make them non-static instead?

Comment: For the same sorts of reasons anyone uses static variables.  We need variables accessible from anywhere in the code, there never needs to be more than once instance, passing around a single instance would be messy and could open up opportunities for a lot of error.  Any changes to those properties made from anywhere need to be synced across the whole program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Json.Net attributes but you are not using the Json.Net serializer.  [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of the .Net Framework, not [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), so it will not honor `[JsonObject]` and `[JsonProperty]` attributes.  Moreover, `DataContractJsonSerializer` does not support serializing static members, even if you do use the correct attributes with it (`[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`, respectively).  You will need to use Json.Net's [`JsonSerializer`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer.htm) instead if you want to serialize static members.

```
using (var stream = File.Create(savePath))
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
using (JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(textWriter))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, o);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYzDEE

Note: if your JSON is small you don't really need to a stream.  You can simplify your code to this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o);
File.WriteAllText(savePath, json, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: That worked, I was just calling a legacy method we created.  The new one was the one updated to JSON.net and it worked fine.  The data we're exporting is also generally quite large.  I just provided a subsample for the post.