# How to include (or replace) static properties in System.Text.Json serialization?

Tags: static, constants, system.text.json

I have some object like this:

```
public class ResponseBase
{
    public string eventType { get; }
    public string eventSourceGuid { get; }
}

public class QueryDevicesResponse : ResponseBase
{
    public new static string eventType { get => "queryDevicesResponse"; }
    public new string eventSourceGuid { get => "0"; }
    public EventData eventData { get; set; }
}
```

`eventType` field is static because I'm trying to:

- minimize lines of code
- use it like "application-wide" string stored (in source code) together with DTO class definition, and use it in some switch and if statements without instantiating `QueryDevicesResponse`.

When I call:

```
QueryDevicesResponse queryDevicesResponse = QueryDevicesResponse.Mock();
JsonSerializer.Serialize.JsonSerializer.Serialize(queryDevicesResponse);
```

I'm getting JSON without `eventType` field. I guess this is because field is static.

**Can I change JsonSerializer behavior to include also static fields?**

This is similar question, but this is about Newtonsoft.Json:

[Why can't JSON .Net serialize static or const member variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597/why-cant-json-net-serialize-static-or-const-member-variables)

Alternatively:

**How can I replace `static` modifier to get similar behavior and keep code small?**

Comment: As far as I know there's no way (in .Net 3.x) to return a static property using `System.Text.Json` other than writing a custom `JsonConverter` for the containing class.  If you want to *use it like "application-wide" string stored (in source code)*, why not put it in a `const` statement?  Or put all the `eventType` string values in const statements in some separate static class?  Also, why not make the property virtual?

Comment: @dbc Well, I tried to keep design as close to POCO as possible. in the end I changed my design by removing static. Now my C# code uses class name in switch and if statements. Thanks for the "there's no way (in .Net 3.x)" information, that could be an answer I would accept. P.s. are we alone here? :D